# Square roots modulo p

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials

For Chebyshev-polynomials on finite fields $F_p$ with a prime $p$, I have found the following expression:

$$
T_n(x)=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}{2} mod\space p.
$$

But obviously, $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is not defined on $F_p$ for some $x$. How can this formula still be a correct representation of Chebyshev-polynomials modulo $p$?

Thanks so much for some help!

Comment: What's wrong with defining it by$$(\sqrt{x})^2\equiv x\mod{p}$$where this exists?

Comment: Has anyone got an idea how to prove the above formula?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The simple fact is that the expression
$$(x+\alpha)^n+(x-\alpha)^n$$
contains no odd powers of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding! Do you know how to prove the expression above? When I set

$a=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$

to use the formula

$T_n(\frac{1}{2}(a+a^{-1}))=\frac{1}{2}(a^n+a^{-n})$

I once again have the problem, that $a$ may not be defined for some $x$... Do you know an alternative there?

Comment: @Ada : If a square root is not in $\Bbb F_p$, then it is in $\Bbb F_{p^2}$. Thus compute in the quadratic extension and check whether the coefficients are actually in $\Bbb F_p$, i.e. the "imaginary" parts cancel out. You get the quadratic extension by adjoining a square root of a non-square.